# Parsing JSON to have a key and a value

Tags: arrays, json, dictionary, key-value

I'm converting a JSON string to a javascript array, and currently I have this:

```
{
    "table1": [
        {
            "EmpNo": "3103899",
            "attendanceStatus": "true"
        }
    ]
}
```

What I need to do now, is convert it to an array that gets `EmpNo` value as Key and `attendanceStatus` as a Value, so that it looks something like this:

```
var attendances = {
    111: false,          
    123: true,
    456: false,
    789: true,
    321: true,
    654: false,
    222: true,
    987: false
};
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your JSON string you only have 1 pair employee-attendance, while in your array you have many. How are the other employees arranged in the original JSON string? Do you have 1 JSON string per employee (i.e., you create the array by combining multiple JSON strings)? Are all the employees listed inside array `table1`? Or something else?

Comment: @user2340612, I have all the employees in one JSON string, so yes, all the employees are listen inside table1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you have the following JSON string:

```
{
  "table1": [
    {
      "EmpNo": "3103899",
      "attendanceStatus": true
    },
    {
      "EmpNo": "123",
      "attendanceStatus": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Then, you can write the following code:

```
var json = JSON.parse('{"table1":[{"EmpNo":"3103899","attendanceStatus":true},{"EmpNo":"123","attendanceStatus":false}]}')

var array = []

json.table1.forEach(function(entry) {
  item = { [entry.EmpNo] : entry.attendanceStatus };
  array.push(item);
})

console.log(array)
```

And that's what you should get in the console:

```
[ { 3103899: true }, { 123: false } ]
```